# Generate sequential Unique ID that is a string from current max Unique ID

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7

I am very new to python, and I need some help. I am trying to write a script that will find the current highest Unique ID in the 'FACILITYID' field from our 'Meter' layer. Then, it will need to write the next highest value to each row with the value 'Null' in the FACILITYID field. For example, the 'FACILITYID' is a string field formatted like 'MET34869'. Is there a way to do this without making a new field with just the numbers?

This is the code I have so far:

```
import arcpy

fc = "Database Connections\gio.SPW.sde\SPW.DBO.WaterDistribution\SPW.DBO.wServiceConnection"
field = ['FACILITYID']

# Select max value.
max_value = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Meters", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"FACILITYID\" In (SELECT MAX(\"FACILITYID\") FROM wServiceConnection)")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] <= max_value:
            row[0] = row[0]
            cursor.next()
        elif row[0] == None:
# need to figure out how to calculate next highest value when FACILITYID is a string
            row[0] = max_value + 1
            cursor.updateRow(row)
            cursor.next()

print "Task Completed"
```

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Comment: Have a look at Esri's Attribute Assistant - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/190225/64785

Comment: @Midavalo is right on, this is _exactly_ what Attribute Assistant is perfect for. I've set it up to do just this type of `FACILITYID` auto-creation on featureclasses such as `wServiceConnection`.

Comment: @Midavalo Attribute Assistant looks great! I will give it a try.

Comment: @Midavalo It's working perfectly. Thank you for the help. :)